# Presentation of a group: Show that $\langle a|a^2\rangle =\{1,a\}$.

Tags: group-theory

Example: $\langle a|a^2\rangle=\{1,a\}$.

After reading the definition of presentation of a group, I find myself cannot understand the above example given. I don't know which part of the definition I have misunderstood, so please show the above statement step by step. Thank you.

Edit:

My interpretation: Let $G=\{a\},\ \langle G\rangle=\{1,a,a^{-1},a^2,{a^{-2}},\ldots\},\ R=\{a^2\}$. $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $\langle G\rangle$ which contains $a^2$. Then $\langle a|a^2 \rangle=G/N$. Can you please give more details?

Comment: It might be easier to help if you wrote down your definition of a group presentation.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right. It's better to write $X = \{a \}$, since that is a generating set, not a group. Then $F = \{1,a,a^{-1},a^2,\ldots \}$ is the free group with the single generator $a$. Define $N$ to be the smallest normal subgroup of $F$ that contains $a^2$. Then $\langle a \mid a^2 \rangle = F/N$. Note that $F$ is just the infinite cyclic group with generator $a$, and $N$ is its subgroup generated by $a^2$ (which is normal), so $F/N$ has order $2$. Strictly speaking $\langle a \mid a^2 \rangle = \{N, Na \}$ rather than $\{ 1,a\}$, but that is standard abuse of notation.

Comment: So $N=\{1,a^{\pm 2},a^{\pm 4},...\}$?

Comment: $\{N,Na\}=F$?????

Comment: Yes, $N = \{1, a^{\pm 2}, a^{\pm 4}, \ldots, \}$, and $\{N,Na \} = F/N$.

Comment: So what exactly $\{N,Na\}$ is? Is it $\{\{1,a^{\pm2},a^{\pm4},...\},\{a^{\pm1},a^{\pm3},a^{\pm5},..\}\}$?

Comment: Yes that's right. But frankly you cannot hope to understand the theory of group presentations if you are uncertain about what subgroups and cosets are.

Comment: Ya, I will work hard, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\langle a\mid a^2\rangle$ denotes the group that consists of finite-length words on the alphabet $\{a,a^{-1}\}$ under the *smallest* equivalence relation that contains $aa\sim \epsilon$ and which is compatible with the law of composition, which is the concatenation of words.

You can use induction to prove that $a^{2n+b}\sim a^b$, where $b\in\{0,1\}$, $n\in\mathbb Z$. Thus the group has at most $2$ elements: the equivalence class of $a^1$, and that of $a^2$ (which is also the equivalence class of $\epsilon$).

To prove that the equivalence class of $a$ and that of $\epsilon$ are distinct, note that $\sim$ is defined as the *smallest congruence* that makes $aa\sim\epsilon$ valid. If we had $a\sim\epsilon$, the $\sim$ relation would identify all the elements, and would not be the *smallest* relation.

Comment: There are several things wrong with your definition. The smallest equivalence relation in which $aa \sim \epsilon$ has all of its equivalence classes except $\{ aa, \epsilon \}$ of size $1$, and they do not form a group. You need a *congruence*, which has extra conditions. Also, you need strings on the alphabet $\{a.a^{-1}\}$ rather than just $\{ a \}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you for pointing this out. Cheers!